# How to force install of Android App in Development Environment?

Tags: android

I'm tired of uninstalling and than reinstalling in development.
Is there a way to do adb -force install some.apk ? I mean this would save a lot of time. Each time going to system ->apps->uninstall every time a signature is different.

Obviously debug is a dev setting so I don't see why one constantly needs to uninstall the app manually, what a waste of time? Anything that can make development easier is going to result in better code, and better apps so whats up with this?

I have hot deployed to server side Java EE servers in less time. This is less an issue on command line, since one could do an uninstall or replace the adb script with an uninstall followed by an install.
However in eclipse its still a pain.  It has been pointed out that this is largely about signature changes. Yes, it is.  But why should signatures change in development, and debug mode, and cause the reinstallation issue?

Comment: I only rarely need to uninstall the app manually - I just say run and it writes over the old one.  Perhaps theres something wrong with your setup?

Comment: why are you changing your signature?

Comment: Well I not specifically trying to change signatures.  I do a code checkout, recompile and signatures are different.

Comment: It is true that signature differences are at the root of this issue.

Comment: It seems like signatures should change as new signatures are requested as a production deployment feature. Not something that happens automatically in development.

Comment: "I do a code checkout, recompile and signatures are different" -- so long as you are using the same keystore (and the same key in the keystore, if you store multiple keys there), you will get an APK with a compatible signature, and it will simply install normally. Of course, the tone of your question is massively unprofessional, so you may not get a lot of help here.

Comment: Even in development, the APK needs to be signed with a key in order to be deployed on a device. If you're developing with multiple development machines it may be that your debug keystores on your separate machines are different. Or you may be mixing development and release APKs signed with different keys.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The normal build process uses the android debug keystore that can be found in your android folder in your home directory (path depends on your OS).

With this debug keystore your app will be signed. This debug signature can be installed on every android device in the world as long as there isn't your app with another signature already installed.

When you say you only do code checkouts, rebuild and your signature is different, than probably your build process is broken. Your debug keystore is valid for at least a year and as long as you are on the same PC while building the generated APK should never have a different signature.

For further checking you should bring some light in your development process. What do you use? Eclipse?

If you work on different developing machines, pick one keystore from one machine and put it into your version control and use this to sign your apk with the debug signature.

Comment: I am using eclipse.  So I guess the keystore needs to be checked in and than this will not be an issue.

Comment: Even without eclipse you should only get this issue when you switch devices with other devs or if you switch from one pc to the next. That can only be changed when one keystore is added in the version control and used for building your apk. If you don't switch and you still have this issue, something with your build process is pretty messed up...

Comment: No, I would actually prefer an explanation with a single line answer (if such answer exists, which actually does), but sadly you have given no single line answer. Also, if you think that the question is generic and there can not have a single line answer, then you should have included answers to specific platforms (like in Rizky's answer) and then asked for the platform used by OP.

Comment: @Nishant I disagree. There are multiple questions the OP stated and just one was answered in the answer from Rizky. One of my top voted answers is a one liner, too. If the answer is valid and complete, there is nothing to argue against one liner. I don't say that Rizky should get less upvotes, that is fine. I argue against the downvotes on my post which tries to address all questions the OP asked.

Answer (score 236):

adb has [-r] parameter to reinstall.

```
adb install -r some.apk
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot! Surprised this wasn't on the adb page.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Receive INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES and INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE in proper cases.

Comment: @kaspartus It doesn't override an app with different signatures (e.g. between debug and production version) for security reasons. I keep an uninstall batch file for those cases.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot! It saves a lot of time for me.

Comment: you can ignore the downgrade issue with the -d tag

Comment: Cool! Downgrade works! Just need: ADB INSTALL -R -D <...apk>

Answer (score 14):

A web search you could have done reveals that the answer to your adb question is:

```
adb uninstall some.package.name
```

Note that it's not the file.apk name you use with adb install, but rather the actual package name it ends up installed as.

Comment: adb uninstall some.package.name  then adb install *.apk inside a single script would work.

Comment: There is a lot of value to answering questions on Stack Overflow even if they can be found with a web search, because next time someone does such a web search, they get your high quality answer. :)

Comment: It's important to also note what other respondents have pointed out - you don't need to uninstall if you are installing a new build with the same signature, and if you are constantly installing with different debug keys it may be better to standardize.  Really the only time you should *need* to do this is when switching a device between a debug and release version of the app.

Comment: However note that this will delete all your data

Comment: The -r didn't work for me, I kept getting the error. However after explicit uninstall of the package I was able to install, so I'm upvoting this.

Answer (score 6):

adb install -r -d path/to/file.apk

-r to replace
-d to force downgrade

Answer (score 3):

You can install an app forcefully by passing **-r** parameter.

**-r** parameter lets adb to reinstall the app.

```
adb install -r app-release.apk
```

Answer (score -2):

The debug keystore can be set in Eclipse in Preferences/Android/Build/Custom debug keystore, which is very helpful when working in a team.  Every member should set up the same keystore there, and then it is no problem any longer to share devices.

Answer (score -6):

for uninstall
adb uninstall app_package_name

for install
adb install app_package_name

into the command prompt in windows 
and terminal in linex/Macos